# HTML Navbar: Elements out of Alignment

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a website for a school project. However, the navbar elements are out of alignment. The navbar Elements are supposed to be in a band, however, they pop half out of the band.

```css
a {
  background-color: #666;
  float: center;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #22A;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <strong>
    <p class="nav">
    <nav>
     <a class="first-a-nav">Home</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">All Models</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">1 to 7 Series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">X series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">M series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">BMW i</a>
    </nav>
    </p>
    </strong>
</div>
```

The CSS part could not be made any shorter, else the `overflow: hidden` works just fine.

To summarize: **My Nabar is totally screwed up**. Please help me to turn it back to normal.

Comment: Start by using [a markup validator](https://validator.nu) and a [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). You have machine detectable errors in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead of using inline everywhere try using inline-block.

```css
a {
  background-color: #666;
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #22A;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <strong>
    <p class="nav">
    <nav>
     <a class="first-a-nav">Home</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">All Models</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">1 to 7 Series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">X series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">M series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">BMW i</a>
    </nav>
    </p>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to like this.

```css
a {
  background-color: #666;
  display: inline;
  padding: 11px 77px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #22A;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <strong>
    <p class="nav">
    <nav>
     <a class="first-a-nav">Home</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">All Models</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">1 to 7 Series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">X series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">M series</a>
     <a class="first-a-nav">BMW i</a>
    </nav>
    </p>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Comment: The text Alignment is still at the left end, while I require it to be at the center

Comment: @Darsh K yes text is center align only check once.

Comment: @Dassh K you talking about which element.If you are not getting then apply `margin: 0 auto;` to the particular div it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, its very simple; 
remove; `background-color: #666;` from the css class `nav`

Comment: I tried it, then there are white gaps in between each link

Comment: yes, it looks like that., you want the menu to have a complete background with out  the spaces remove the`background-color: #666;`  from `a`